# Curious SIGSEGV error in the code

Tags: c++, runtime-error, out-of-memory, segmentation-fault

The following code is giving SGSEGV error for high inputs
Constraints:
1<=t<=5

1<=n<=10^6

-10<= z <= 10
I have declared adequate amount of memory.
Declared large memories globally even then i am getting a sigsegv error.Cant figure out the reasons.Any hints?

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 #define _ ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
 using namespace std;
 int s[1000000];
 int main(){_
int t;
cin>>t;
while(t--){
    int n,i,z,sum=0,p,cnt=0;
    unsigned long long int ans=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>z;
        sum+=z;
        s[i]=sum;
    }
    sort(s,s+n);
    i=0;
    while(i<n){
        p=s[i];
        cnt=0;
        while(s[i]==p){
            cnt++;
            i++;
        }
        ans=ans+(((unsigned long long)cnt*(cnt-1))>>1);
    }
    cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n && s[i]<=0;i++){
        if(s[i]==0){
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    ans+=cnt;
    cout<<ans<<"\n";
}
return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It looks like you might be running out of stack space. Maybe try replacing `int s[1000000];` with `int *s = new int[1000000];`? Alternatively, I would check and make sure you aren't trying to access an element which is out-of-bounds of `s[]` - try adding some debug code to print `i` when it is `>= 1000000` and see what happens.

Comment: how is int s[1000000]; different from int *s = new int[1000000];What difference could it make? curious

Comment: When you declare a variable without using `malloc` or `new`, it is declared on the stack (which is potentially limited), whereas if you actually allocate new memory via `malloc` or `new`, then it is allocated on the heap - which is mostly only limited by the amount of RAM your system has.

Comment: -1 for posting a question with a crash involved without the basic courtesy of a backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop:

```
while(s[i] == p) {
    cnt++;
    i++;
}
```

potentially runs off the end of `s` and crashes.  Change it to

```
while (i < n && s[i] == p)
```

In general, when you (consistently) get a crash, run your progam with a debugger, and it will tell you WHERE it crashed.  With that you should be able to figure out what is going wrong.